# separar los datos de un array

Tags: php, api, woocommerce

**me pueden aydar a sacar los datos del array ya que estoy usando la api de woocomerce y todos los datos me los trae en el array y quiero sacar los datos de ese array para poderlos enviar a una base de datos  y trabajarlos mejor espero que me puedan ayudar gracias  **

[image: Quiero sacar los datos que estan dentro de los arrays y que me los pueda mostrar mas organizados espero que me puedan ayudar gracias]

```
$wii = $woocommerce->get('orders');
    

    
    $result[] = $wii;

    foreach ($wii as $key ) {
        

        print_r($key);
    }
```

Comment: Intentastes `echo json_encode($wii)`?

Comment: ya lo intente pero lo muestra de otra forma el array y me aparece este error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

**aca ya me separo los datos pero solo me trae un producto por id como puedo hacer ahora para que me los traiga todos los datos que tengo como si fuera una tabla de registros en donde me traer todos los datos  **

```
if (isset($_POST['consult'])) {
        $id = $_POST['orden'];
    }
    $wii = $woocommerce->get('orders/'.$id);
    

     
    
    
    $result[] = '';

    foreach ($wii as $key => $value ) {
        $result[$key]= $value;

        
    }

    return $result;



    
    
    

    
}
```

}

$new = new woo();
$apiwoo = $new->orders();

echo $apiwoo['id'];