# como puedo sacar los datos de un array que estan dentro de otro array

Tags: php, woocommerce

**estoy trabajando con la RES API  de woocomerce y los datos que me traen estan dentro de un array los primeros datos que estan ya los saque pero hay datos hijos que estan en un array tambien como podria sacar esos demas datos **

Comment: Esta pregunta es u duplicado de [separar los datos de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417465/separar-los-datos-de-un-array)

Answer (score 0):

Si tiene un objeto adentro con una flecha. `$arr["producto"]->nombre`.
otras opción si no tiene un objeto es `$arr["producto"]["nombre"]`